# Disable choose an option in configurable products of Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to disable choose an option in configurable products drop-down.Rather it should automatically select a default product. Where and what to edit?

Answer (score 4):

You can have those changes in the following file.

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```

And Better work with "Template Path Hints" Enabled from the backend. You will know what and where you need to customize.

**UPDATE:**

Open this file:

> /app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Right below

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(< ?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

add this JavaScript code:

```
//we create new function
spConfig.setInitialState = function(dropdown_id)
{
//select dropdown
var dropdown = $(dropdown_id);
//remove empty option from dropdown so it is not selectable after initial selection
dropdown[0].remove();
//change selections in dropdowns
for(index = 0; index < dropdown.length; index++)
{
if(dropdown[index].value != "")
{
dropdown.selectedIndex = index;
var element = dropdown;
var event = 'change';
//fire events
if(document.createEventObject)
{
var evt = document.createEventObject();
return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
}
else
{
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent(event, true, true );
return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
}
}
};
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
spConfig.setInitialState("attribute< ?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>")
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For more information See [Here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-make-configurable-options-autoselected-on-configurable-product-view-page/) and more [Here](http://icebergcommerce.com/software/blog/iss/article/magento-configurable-products-setting-default-value-for-options)

Full Working file

> /app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

```
<?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
    <dl>
    <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
        <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
        </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
      //we create new function
        spConfig.setInitialState = function(dropdown_id)
        {
        //select dropdown
        var dropdown = $(dropdown_id);
        //remove empty option from dropdown so it is not selectable after initial selection
        dropdown[0].remove();
        //change selections in dropdowns
        for(index = 0; index < dropdown.length; index++)
        {
        if(dropdown[index].value != "")
        {
        dropdown.selectedIndex = index;
        var element = dropdown;
        var event = 'change';
        //fire events
        if(document.createEventObject)
        {
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
        }
        else
        {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true );
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
        }
        }
        };
        <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        spConfig.setInitialState("attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>")
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: not working when i add this  code at respective area.choose an option  still displays

Comment: Are you supplying the proper $_attribute->getAttributeId()

Comment: ya everything done as told but if i am adding then price not changing and choose an option still remains

Comment: Updated my answer with full code. Its working at my side perfectly.

Comment: hi first of all the path u gave me such path doesnot exist in my project.. actually i am using AMASTY colour swatch extension so my congigurable.phtml is different

Comment: how to paste code here stack overfow not allowing me

Comment: Dushyant Joshi can u share me ur email id need to have a chat with u

Comment: You can post the code in the question itself by editing your question

Comment: mine gmail id---  "ctcpoltu@gmail.com" plz send a chat request

Comment: I have a followup question... If I have 2 or more attributes and I change the default selection on the 1st attribute, how can I prevent the 2nd and 3rd options from reverting to "Choose an Option..."?  I'd like those to remain selected.

Comment: @NotJay, could you post this as new question, so that others can also look

Comment: @DushyantJoshi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945102/magento-configurable-product-drop-down-menu-select-option-and-keep-other-drop  Thanks in advance!