# How to remove choose an option in configurable product in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am building a magento project. In configurable product, before choosing an option, price is being displayed. I need to modify it like either hide price until user choose an option or make any one option as default in dropdown. I have gone through google and found a script to hide choose an option in dropdown. But it is not working. I`m using magento 1.8.

Can you guys please guide me to achieve this. Here is the link of code I found:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-make-configurable-options-autoselected-on-configurable-product-view-page/

Answer (score 2):

**How to remove the "Choose an Option" element from the drop down**

*Tested with Magento v1.9.2.1*

Add the following JavaScript to your page. There is only 3 lines here that have been edited from the original logic found in `js/varien/configurable.js`. I've left these lines in there, commented out for you to see what has been modified.

```
Product.Config.prototype.fillSelect = function(element){
    var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, '');
    var options = this.getAttributeOptions(attributeId);
    this.clearSelect(element);
    //element.options[0] = new Option('', '');
    //element.options[0].innerHTML = this.config.chooseText;

    var prevConfig = false;
    if(element.prevSetting){
        prevConfig = element.prevSetting.options[element.prevSetting.selectedIndex];
    }

    if(options) {
        //var index = 1;
        var index = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
            var allowedProducts = [];
            if(prevConfig) {
                for(var j=0;j<options[i].products.length;j++){
                    if(prevConfig.config.allowedProducts
                        && prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j])>-1){
                        allowedProducts.push(options[i].products[j]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                allowedProducts = options[i].products.clone();
            }

            if(allowedProducts.size()>0){
                options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                element.options[index] = new Option(this.getOptionLabel(options[i], options[i].price), options[i].id);
                if (typeof options[i].price != 'undefined') {
                    element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].price);
                }
                element.options[index].config = options[i];
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Kandarp B Patel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005824/disable-choose-an-option-in-configurable-products-of-magento) may help you remove "Choose an option" option. It provides some modifications to Inchoo's code on the page you referenced.

Magento's forum answered [how to remove the price from the configurable product options dropdown](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/76184/).

Alternatively, you could [remove configurable option pricing with jQuery](http://www.cybernetikz.com/blog/remove-price-configurable-products-dropdown-options-magento/).